# Using Iron Ruby classes in native Ruby class

Tags: ruby, interop, ironruby

I'm wondering if an Iron Ruby class/object can be used in a native ruby interpreter(irb) driven class(using a gem sort of a thing) ? The main problem is that I have a ruby class that is using some gems(Ex: nokogiri) which are not compatible with Iron Ruby and Iron Ruby class is using .Net libraries. So in short, I want to know if there are any ways to communicate with iron ruby classes in native ruby. If there are any alternatives to solve this, please do mention them.

Answer (score 2):

No other way than having two different processes for each ruby interpreter running with some kind of communication. You could use [distributed ruby](http://segment7.net/projects/ruby/drb/introduction.html) for that. Anyway, the best thing to do is to not use .Net libraries and replace them with something else from ruby world.